# How to prevent elements inside div from overflowing?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make these red squares when they reach the end of div , start new column from above and continue downward and so on .... BUT HERE WHEN THEY REACH THE END OF DIV tHE OVERFLOW I know this sound silly but I am doing iit for a school project and thanks ..

```css
.umbrella {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: grey;
}

.square {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="umbrella">
  <div class="square"> Hello1</div>
  <div class="square"> Hello1</div>
  <div class="square"> Hello1</div>
  <div class="square"> Hello1</div>
  <div class="square"> Hello1</div>
  <div class="square"> Hello1</div>
  <div class="square"> Hello1</div>
  <div class="square"> Hello1</div>
  <div class="square"> Hello1</div>
  <div class="square"> Hello1</div>
  <div class="square"> Hello1</div>
  <div class="square"> Hello1</div>
  <div class="square"> Hello1</div>
  <div class="square"> Hello1</div>
  <div class="square"> Hello1</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`display: flex` is your friend, with the settings shown below...

```css
.umbrella {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: grey;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  }

.square {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
}
.square.x {
  width: 150px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="umbrella">
  <div class="square"> Hello1</div>
  <div class="square"> Hello1</div>
  <div class="square"> Hello1</div>
  <div class="square x"> Hello1</div>
  <div class="square"> Hello1</div>
  <div class="square"> Hello1</div>
  <div class="square"> Hello1</div>
  <div class="square"> Hello1</div>
  <div class="square"> Hello1</div>
  <div class="square"> Hello1</div>
  <div class="square"> Hello1</div>
  <div class="square"> Hello1</div>
  <div class="square"> Hello1</div>
  <div class="square x"> Hello1</div>
  <div class="square"> Hello1</div>
</div>
```

Here's another solution using CSS colums. `column-count` determines the number of columns, depending on that number they will be equally wide.

```css
.umbrella {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: grey;
  column-count: 2;
  }

.square {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
}
.square.x {
  width: 150px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="umbrella">
  <div class="square"> Hello1</div>
  <div class="square"> Hello1</div>
  <div class="square"> Hello1</div>
  <div class="square x"> Hello1</div>
  <div class="square"> Hello1</div>
  <div class="square"> Hello1</div>
  <div class="square"> Hello1</div>
  <div class="square"> Hello1</div>
  <div class="square"> Hello1</div>
  <div class="square"> Hello1</div>
  <div class="square"> Hello1</div>
  <div class="square"> Hello1</div>
  <div class="square"> Hello1</div>
  <div class="square"> Hello1</div>
  <div class="square"> Hello1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: actually flex is ok but not an absolute answer because if I change the width of one square it will miss up the entire aligment of content so can you help me with other css property ... THANKS ALOT ...

Comment: I don't understand what you mean - look at my changed snippet, there's *one* element with `width: 150px` in there now - what would you like to happen to that one?

Comment: no I mean in the first column when you change one square width the second column whole will be pushed beacuse of this one square this is the only problem that is giving me nightmares :)

Comment: flex will simply distribute the available spavce evenly - see my snippet oonce more with another change

Comment: But note another addition / second snippet which uses `column-count` (no flex)

Comment: yep that does the trick thanks alot  Johannes  ( military solute )

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with flex:

```css
.umbrella {
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  background: grey;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  flex-direction:column;
}

.square {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="umbrella">
  <div class="square"> Hello1</div>
  <div class="square"> Hello1</div>
  <div class="square"> Hello1</div>
  <div class="square"> Hello1</div>
  <div class="square"> Hello1</div>
  <div class="square"> Hello1</div>
  <div class="square"> Hello1</div>
  <div class="square"> Hello1</div>
  <div class="square"> Hello1</div>
  <div class="square"> Hello1</div>
  <div class="square"> Hello1</div>
  <div class="square"> Hello1</div>
  <div class="square"> Hello1</div>
  <div class="square"> Hello1</div>
  <div class="square"> Hello1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: as above... flex actually is ok but not an absolute answer because if I change the width of one square it will miss up the entire aligment of content so can you help me with other css property ... THANKS ALOT ...

Comment: @JOJO how the alignment is messed when changing the width :) i don't see any issue when changing the width, or maybe you requirements aren't clear enough